# Cannot reachable php-mysql connection from html code

Tags: php, sql

I'm callling php function in html code. But connection between mysql and php is failed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="index.php">go to main page</a></h1>
    <?php actorList()?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "*","final");
    if(!$conn) die("Connection failed!");
    function actorList(){
      global $conn;
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM actor_list");
    }
?>
```

Why I cannot use `$conn` in actorList?

Comment: What is the error result?  What does your page display?

Comment: check extension of your file, is it `.php`?

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov yes it is `select.php`

Comment: You also need a semicolon after the function call (`actorList();`)

Comment: @Sablefoste connection is sucessful out of function but not in the function

Comment: @haram, how do you know?  You don't output anything.  For example, add `var_dump($result)` as the last line in your function and see what you get.

Comment: @Sablefoste I tried `if(!conn) echo 'hello'` out of function and in the function

Comment: Try the `var_dump` I mentioned above.  Or add `return $result;` as the last line of the function, and change your function call above to `echo actorList();`

Comment: try to put the connection inside the function just for testing
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "qotktk12","final");
    if(!$conn) die("Connection failed!");
after the global

Comment: @Geomorillo oh... I put my password in the post.. can you delete your comment?

Comment: @Sablefoste `var_dump($result)` is `NULL`

Comment: Okay, the next question then is do you have any records in your table `actor_list`?

Comment: @Sablefoste yep I had a records in every table. the problem is that `$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "*","final");` acts in the function but I cannot use as a global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass into a param instead?

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "qotktk12","final");
if(!$conn) die("Connection failed!"); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="index.php">go to main page</a></h1>
    <?php actorList($conn)?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    function actorList($conn){
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM actor_list");
    }
?>
```

Or this way will work

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");
    if(!$conn) die("Connection failed!");
    function actorList(){
      global $conn;
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM actor_list");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href="index.php">go to main page</a></h1>
    <?php actorList()?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess, what happen is that you call actorList() before the global variable have been set thats why the variable is null

Comment: Thx!~ I got it.